# How to seed data into a postgres database table from a .csv file?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, csv

I am trying to seed data into a psql table from a .csv file. 
This is the setup:

data.csv:
`name,price,section
Aluminum Foil,8.84,miscellaneous
Apples,10.81,produce`

I am using the `pg` module in Node to connect to database `grocery_store` that has 1 table `grocery_items` with columns `id, name, price and section`.

```
const Client = require('pg').Client
const connectionString = 'postgresql://localhost:5432/grocery_store'
const pg = new Client( { connectionString: connectionString } )
```

How can I now seed data from `data.csv` into the `grocery_items` table?

I've tried the `pg-copy-streams` module and they suggest to do:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var pg = require('pg');
var copyFrom = require('pg-copy-streams').from;

pg.connect(function(err, client, done) {
  var stream = client.query(copyFrom('COPY my_table FROM STDIN'));
  var fileStream = fs.createReadStream('some_file.tsv')
  fileStream.on('error', done);
  fileStream.pipe(stream).on('finish', done).on('error', done);
});
```

But I got `pg.connect` is not a function error when I tried this.

Comment: Mysql is a different product.

Comment: @baibhavx did you get this to work? I am curious about the same question.

Comment: @MihirPatel `\copy grocery_items(name, price, section) FROM './data.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;` solved my problem!

Answer (score 7):

It should work fine.

**Create your table:**

```
CREATE TABLE my_table 
(name varchar(50), price int, section varchar(50));
```

**Copy data from your CSV file to the table:**

```
COPY my_table FROM '/path/to/csv/my_table.txt' WITH (FORMAT csv);
```